# how Apollo client optimisticResponse working

Tags: apollo, apollostack, apollo-server

http://dev.apollodata.com/react/mutations.html

I am trying out with `optimisticResponse`, but i am confused... and couldn't get it working on my local.

My questions are:

1. will `optimisticResponse` update the `props` and hence the re-render? how important is `__typename: 'Mutation'` can you leave it?
2. `updateQueries` is for new record appear? is this function trigger automatically or you need to invoke it?

is there any full example of out there which include the apollo server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found:

```
const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface('http://localhost:8080/graphql');
    this.client = new ApolloClient({
        networkInterface,
        dataIdFromObject: r => r.id
    }
);
```

dataIdFromObject is the one thing i am missing during the Apolloclient initiation

```
dataIdFromObject (Object) => string
A function that returns a object identifier given a particular result object.
```

it will give unique ID for all result object.